# Why didn't govt. consider nuking Terraforming Machines with Nuclear Weapons?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In *Man of Steel* movie, fighter jet squads tried to blow Terraforming Machine above Metropolis (which eventually failed because of increased gravity in that area). Instead of this, why didn't govt. consider nuking Terraforming Machines with Nuclear Weapons? Those alien machines were posing threat to Earth (could be thought because of lack of info) and humanity. So, it wasn't a small scale threat.

Comment: I doubt they would sanction nuclear strikes in such a densely populated area

Comment: While wildly out of the scope, that was the reason given for initially not using nuclear weapons in "Independence Day", for much the same thing (Alien spacecraft hovering over major cities.)

Comment: Considering the level of technological sophistication of the Kryptonians, a weapon as primitive as a nuclear weapon should have no chance of working against any of their technology. The Kryptonians hacked the communication protocols of every television or radio on Earth. Turning off a nuke's guidance system should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Even a kinetic cruise missile (such as the ones the Chinese have) would probably have done the trick. However, as in many superhero/godzilla movies, that would decrease from the fun of the movie. (Would you rather pay to watch a kinetic strike or a superhero beat the stuffing out of it? If you answered #1, watch the US interception of the dead satellite USA-193 as it reentered the atmosphere in 2008. It was televised and everything.)

Comment: @Monty The city below that thing was almost destroyed.

Comment: @JohnP Wasn't use of Nuclear Weapon over New York City sanctioned in *Avengers* movie?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Yes, I believe so. And it was also sanctioned in ID for one strike after the initial refusal.

Comment: Not by that point it hadn't been.  Metropolis wasn't damaged until *after* the weapon began firing, by that point the US Army already had the plan to assault the Kryptonian ship in motion.

Comment: Jet fighters' missiles were unable to hit them because of increased gravity. Some jet fighters even crashed due to it. When gravity was increased, it means Terraforming machines were already in action. Isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

For all we know, they *did* consider it. The level at which such decisions would be made (President & highest-level military) is not one into which the film gives any insight.

As for why they didn't do it -- well, nuking your largest, most populated and arguably most culturally important city is not a decision to be taken lightly, and it would be a *very* big ask for any President to order something that would normally be unthinkable within the few hours that the World Engine was active for.

Nuking the counterpart machine in the Indian ocean would be more palatable to the Americans, but that would also have a whole host of problems attached to it, and it's entirely believable that they would not reach such a decision in the short time-span allowed.

Comment: Sounds right, and I would add that the Kryptonian tactics involve some shock and awe, which strategically means it goes so far over the top that reaction is stalled.